# How to change sharepoint 2013 left-to-right orientation to right-to-left

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

Quick Question: How to change the SharePoint 2013 orientation from left-to-right to right-to-left ?

I'll still be using English as Default language!!

Thanks,
Pandiarajan